# Immutable read-only objects vs object with automatic properties

Tags: c#

I've been wondering about this for a while and haven't been able to find much commentary on the subject and haven't been able to come on a conclusion by myself.

When creating objects, it's accepted best practice to make the object as limited as possible in terms of exposing data and allowing that data to manipulated. If you can make an object immutable, especially in multi-threaded applications, then it is best to do so.

Having said that, C# seems to favor the developer who doesn't follow this rule by allowing the definition of a class to be much more simple, and more importantly, easier to maintain.

Take the following read-only immutable class:

```
public class ActiveDirectoryUser
{
    private readonly string firstName, lastName, office, username, email;

    public ActiveDirectoryUser(string firstName, string lastName, string office, string username, string email)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.office = office;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
    }

    ...

    public string Email
    {
        get { return email; }
    }
}
```

And compare it to the much more simple example as below, which isn't read-only.

```
public class ActiveDirectoryUser
{
    public string FirstName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    ...

    public string Email
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Which can be instantiated with the following is:

```
ActiveDirectoryUser user = 
    new ActiveDirectoryUser
       { FirstName= "Sam", LastName = "Shiles", ..., Email ="Sam@shiles.com" };
```

Given the simpler definition, the fewer lines of code, the less chance for developer error and the ease with which another developer can understand the code (especially with examples that are more true to life than our simple example), is the value of creating proper read-only, immutable objects, worth the cost?

Also, do other people believe that making immutable objects in C# should be made easier with an automatic-esq syntax such as:

```
public string FirstName {get; readonly set;}
```

Comment: Does your second example really work? So far as I'm aware, you'll still need to provide a constructor.

Comment: No it can't, you second example won't work

Comment: Sorry, updated the question.

Comment: Your update is not readonly.

Comment: "the less chance for developer error" - maybe want to revisit that statement :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Given the simpler definition, the fewer lines of code, the less chance for developer error and the ease with which another developer can understand the code (especially with examples that are more true to life than our simple example), is the value of creating proper read-only, immutable objects, worth the cost?

Yes.

I note that nothing is stopping you from saying

```
int Foo { get; private set; }
```

and then using the setter only in the constructor, to guarantee immutability of the property. You just don't get the nice object initializer syntax, but you could create a constructor easily enough.

> Also, do other people believe that making immutable objects in C# should be made easier with an automatic-esq syntax...

Yes. In particular, the C# language design team believes that.

C# 3.0 added a number of features that make C# a more "immutable-friendly" language: anonymous types, query comprehensions and expression trees in particular encourage an immutable-data "functional" style of programming. It also added features that make C# a more "mutable-friendly" language: automatic properties, object initializers and type-inferred arrays come to mind.

The language design team is well aware that these latter features have made it easier to create mutable objects at the same time as the DLR team was making a huge library of immutable expression tree types. The irony was not lost on them, I can assure you.

There are many proposals floating around the language design team for better syntactic sugars for making immutable objects. The fact that object initializers, which require mutability, have almost identical syntax as anonymous type initializers, which are immutable, is an obvious starting point for exploration, but not the only one.

All that said, of course, first, I no longer speak on behalf of the language design team, and second, there is no announced future version of C# beyond the Roslyn project. Thus, speculation as to possible feature sets for hypothetical future versions of the language is just that: speculation on my part.

Comment: Do you still have to say "hypothetical future versions of the language" now that you don't work at MS? Surely you're aware as to whether C# 6.0 had been budgeted for or not by the time you left.

Comment: @mgsam I now know less, not more, about the schedule. And supposing I did know the schedule, which I don't. Would I be likely to poison my good working relationship with my friends on my former team and set myself up for legal liability by posting secret information?

Comment: I said, "*by the time you left*", meaning as to the best of your knowledge. It’s a shame MS considers it a “secret” as to whether they are continuing to develop their flagship language. For those of us who use C# to make a living, it's nice to have an idea of what's ahead more frequently than every two years; a problem that will now be compounded with no public face to the C# team.

Answer (score 3):

> is the value of creating proper read-only, immutable objects, worth the cost?

That depends on how much you care about immutability, thread safety and how much you trust other developers to not make mistakes with them.

I would ask the opposite - is the cost in possible threading mistakes worth the value of creating mutable objects really fast and simply?

Comment: The cost of making C# more complex is certainly worth the the value of making immutable classes easier to define.

Answer (score 1):

When I ponder on these questions I tend to divide code into a few categories.

- Application level
- Internal Framework level
- Public Api level

On application level, your classes will most often be leaf classes that is designed to implement a very specific feature within your project scope. They are seldom candidates for re-use and the only dependencies on them are other specific classes in the application itself.

Here I allow myself some freedom and I would say that a couple of public properties does not hurt anyone. It's all very localized anyway and as application changes, you still need to understand how you code interacts to make any changes to this code. However, freedom does not equal sloppy.

On Framework level, I mean subsystems that is highly re-usable between projects. Could be your salt+hash password classes that has been proven to work over the years. Or maybe a wrapper around an entire third-party product you are dependent on in several projects.

Once you reference such a assembly or if the the source files are added to your solution, your application can still be seen as the only consumer of that code. But that code still has to be very contained and should promise to adhere to contracts. If public properties allows for objects to have corrupt state I would say it's a pretty lame framework.

On Api level things changes drastically. Now you are designing code that are supposed to be used by many subscribers over time. Just not to get confused with terms, the obvious candidate here is .NET Framework itself. But if you are the one providing an api, that people may even pay for with warranty; you really want a stable system that cannot be abused so easily.

What I think is interesting (and mildly amusing) is that all the good principles that have come from OOP-purists and SOLID-purists (and other purists), seems to default to the assumption that all their code is in that high-end support api-level.

So to answer your question, I'll give you a couple of questions to think about

- Will this object change state?
- Will changes corrupt assumptions other pieces of code have?
- If so, would any sane use of my objects actually be abused that way?
- If my objects are insanely abused is this a local bug or a major support issue?
- What level of protection do I actually need here?
- How much effort shall I put into it?
- Does this come with any documentation?

For an explicit example. In a web project I am quite proud of, a lot of data is cached in singletons (static classes really). We do lock correctly to ensure thread-safety on the GetOrSet. Except for one minor detail. We hand out references to the actual objects in our cache to multiple threads. They are mutable and any attempt to write to their public properties could cause all sorts of problems. Now do we clone them? Make them immutable? Take the performance hit of copying these objects so they can cause no harm? Nope. As we are the only consumer of our own caches, we just took a decision that all data coming from a service should be treated as read only. We use Automapper when we do need a copy. And we check up on this during code review.  It works very well. While we had a few bugs, none has of yet been caused by writing to a mutable object.

Patient: - My legs hurt when I jump like this.

Doctor: - Then don't jump like that!

Comment: Really good answer. If it wasn't for an reply from Eric, this would have been the answer.

Comment: Speaking of Eric. Compare my caching strategy to how Roslyn was designed. Quite the opposite. My code is to be consumed by my code, while Roslyn is to be consumed by others.

Answer (score 0):

Not withstanding that your second example is incorrect (it's not immutable, you should add a constructor that takes arguments matching your fields) I would say it can be as the readonly modifier signifies your intent when you were writing the class. This means in the future when other are modifying the class they will know that the fields are readonly not that they are just effectively readonly.

Comment: When no constructor is defined, a default constructor is used so the second example is correct.

Comment: @ken2k good point. Although it is still not immutable. I'll edit it.